# Can we measure little $g$ in this way?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, rotational-kinematics

If a cup of water (known mass) is whirled round at the end of a string, and we look for the exact angular velocity which makes water remain in the cup, is it possible, by knowing the force equilibrium, to measure  [little $g$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth)?

It is a problem that I thought and not a homework..

Comment: I don't see why not. Water will describe a concave parabola inside the cup and the parameters are related to g.

Comment: I am learning physics and am not very sure how to start and try to solve @Mauricio

Comment: https://youtu.be/1F5yPSalXb8

Comment: How much accuracy do you need?  Also, are you measuring any properties of the water in the cup, such as the shape it takes and where in the cup the water sits?  I guess it depends on what you mean by "exact angular velocity which makes water remain in the cup".  If you apply angular acceleration right to the point it's about to spill, and you know the water volume and container geometry; you should be able to.  Finding the range of angular velocities that keep it in the cup could also allow you to find a possible range for $g$.

Comment: Does water takes different shapes? I didn't understand what you mean. It is just for curiosity, not need very much precision. And suppose we know vessel geometry and water volume. I am not sure why do we need to know geometry anyway. Thanks a lot for the comment @JMac

Comment: @santimirandarp Water should form predictable shapes as it spins at different velocities and different ways.  For example, if the cup is in pure rotation (i.e. not being swung around, but sitting in the middle of a turntable), the surface of the water will form a parabola due to inertial effects on the fluid.  If it's swinging around a different point, the shape will be different; but can still be worked out from the math.  You can do this in reverse and determine the shape's dependence on $g$; and using the shape and angular velocity, determine what it would be.  A bit extreme for you maybe.

Comment: @JMac anyway, the question was about a circular movement of the whole system (water and vessel) but in a plane perpendicular to earth's surface. I suppose the question was well-written. It could be just a stone and not water in a vessel..

Comment: If you have a, brace yourself, "record player", you can use that. Especially: a HiFi--put a pot of water on it at 0, 33-1/3, 45, and 78 rpm and measure the max height. That's should give $g$ using the same principle.

Comment: @JEB: why did you put record player in quotes?

Comment: -1 If you are asking for help with making a calculation then this is an **exercise** so the homework-and-exercises tag and policy apply. Asking if it is possible is not useful because Yes/No answers are not useful. It would be more appropriate to visit the ChatRoom to discuss the problem.

Comment: @sammygerbil is not home q because I thought the problem and am just asking for help to start solving

Comment: I did not say that it is homework.

Comment: It is the same as exercise. I mean, I didn't ask for anyone to solve it. Just some help @sammygerbil

Comment: @KyleKanos Because the OP said he was just learning physics, so I guessed he is young (maybe not--it's never too late), and hence maybe never heard of such a device-esp. the 3-speeds.

Comment: I have never hear that..But will look up on the web..@JEB

Comment: @JEB I guess, just find it weird to put the things actual name in quotes--I'd have used italics with a link myself.

Answer (score 0):

Note that ${ω^2r}\ge{g}$.

Even if the centripetal acceleration is greater than $g,$ the water will stay put.So measurements of $g $ will be very rough.

Comment: Which looks great written on paper but blithely ignores the practical difficulties of working a measurement on that basis.